# Managing Java9 modules with third-party libraries

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

My team has recently started to use the Jigsaw modules (experimentally) that was introduced with Java 9.  We are currently on Java 11.  Right from the start we stumble upon problem after problem.  In our experience Springboot 2 and Jigsaw modules don't play well together.

Actually, we encountered many different types of problems which mostly stem from the same root cause: third-party libraries don't define their own `module-info.java`.  These libraries then become unnamed modules which are likely to introduce a conflict.  A common example is:

```
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules A and B export package X.Y.Z to module C
```

Two external libraries, which our team does not intend to modify the source code of, have the same package names which causes the above error.  We find a couple of *'solutions'* online which involve patching modules, but that would take so much maintenance that we wonder if all that effort is worth the result.  We are still at a pretty minimal project (aside from the Spring ecosystem) and fear that these type of problems will grow out of proportion as our list of dependencies increases.

My concrete questions would be: Are there any easier ways to resolve the above `ResolutionException` besides patching modules?  Are there guidelines available on how to deal with third-party libraries?  The fact that most popular frameworks don't bother implementing a `module-info.java` gives the appearance that no-one uses modules so there's no need to support it.

Comment: I’d say this is working as intended.  If you have two libraries providing the same package, you have a classic “jar hell” problem:  which version of that package will actually get used?  I would re-examine whether libraries which do something so irresponsible are up to the quality your application deserves, and I would look into alternatives.  If that’s not possible, I would seriously consider disassembling and reassembling such .jar files without packages that aren’t “theirs.”